# Dot notation with Gradle 3.5 and Spring Boot

Tags: gradle, spring-boot

I'm stuck with the usage of dot notation in Gradle build scripts.

I have a multi project build with a main project and sub projects.

Then main build.gradle is something like this

```
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    dependencies {
        compile "org.slf4j:slf4j-api:${project.'slf4j.version'}",
                'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    }
}
```

The sub project for the web application is build like this

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '1.5.3.RELEASE'
    id 'eclipse-wtp'
    id 'war'
}
dependencies {
    compile (project(":${rootProject.name}-API")){transitive=false}

    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter",
            "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security"
}
```

The build scripts are not complete.
I found out, that one can use a gradle.properties in the main project to define the versions.

```
logback.version=1.2.3
slf4j.version=1.7.25
slf4jVersion=1.7.25
spring.version=4.3.8.RELEASE
```

**1. Question**
How can I use variables with dot notation? I tried that with `$slf4j.version` but the Gradle build process failed.

**2. Question**
Where can I find a complete List of all variables that are supported by the spring boot plugin? I searched for hours with no luck.

**1. Update**
First question was answered by @Vampire.
I update the build.gradle with  `${project.'slf4j.version'}`

Comment: I don't know if this answers your second question, but this [pom.xml file from the spring boot git repository](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-dependencies/pom.xml) looks promising to contain what you want to know. At least all of the dependencies in dot notation you've listed are available as part of the "<properties>" section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `project.'slf4j.version'` to access a property that has a dot in the name, or alternatively `project.properties['slf4j.version']` or `project.getProperty('slf4j.version')` should also work.

Comment: Both questions are answered. See at the comment from @l00tr. I flag this as answer...

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using `versions.slf4j` and `versions.logback` etc instead of `slf4j.version` and `logback.version` then you could do:

```
ext {
    versions = [
        slf4j: '1.7.25',
        logback: '1.2.3'
    ]
}
dependencies {
    compile "org.slf4j:slf4j-api:$versions.slf4j"
}
```

Comment: Not an answer, because using different variable names then Spring Boot is not the right solution...